# NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbModalRef

Tags: angular, typescript, nebular

### I try to use NgbModalRef to close a Modal (That open with NgbModal) and in some components I see the Error:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(MyModule)[NgbModalRef -> NgbModalRef -> NgbModalRef -> NgbModalRef -> NgbModalRef]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbModalRef!

---

Note1:I have imported and Injected NgbModalRef and NgbModal in my component and tried using NgbModule in my appModule and it didnt Work!
Note2:I saw somewhere that people say to write NgbModalRef in appModule provider,and i dont think its the right way because its not a Service!!
Can anyone please help..

Comment: any other module you are using other than app.module ?

Comment: You would get more help if you add your code for us to be able to reproduce the problem. Wild guess: NbDialogModule it's not included in the module of the component you are using the NgbModalRef as @GaurangDhorda said.

Comment: actually I use like 10 or more modules and appModule is my main Module,and I got this Error in some of them not All (codes to open and close modals are same in all )! @GaurangDhorda

Comment: import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';                                   
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
constructor(
 private modalService: NgbModal,
 public activeModal: NgbActiveModal)

 const modalRef = this.modalService.open(StudentComponent as Component);

 dismiss() {
    this.activeModal.dismiss('cancel');
  }    @arunes

Comment: That's okay.. but have you used model component in other module to ? @mohammadreza

Comment: yes @GaurangDhorda

Comment: Then you need to imoort NgbModule inside that module too! @mohammadreza

Comment: i just did what you said and it didnt work @GaurangDhorda

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem using this reference.

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1832#issuecomment-331798666

from  `private modalReference: NgbModalRef;`

to   `private modalReference: any;`